# Feeds module and feed that includes external files as nodes

Tags: feeds

I have a feed that includes item content in external xml files. For example, I have a manifest.xml file that has "sections" and each section links to another xml file.. such as:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<script/>
<channel>
<title>Example</title>
<link>manifest.xml</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 27 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 17:04:05 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<title>Page One</title>
<link>Page_One_Section.xml</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 27 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

Then in that (section) external file contains lists of nodes whos content is stored in yet another external xml file...such as

```
<rss version="2.0">
<script/>
<channel>
<title>Page One</title>
<link>Page_One_Section.xml</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 27 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 17:04:05 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<title>Example Story</title>
<link>story.xml</link>
<pubDate>Fri, 27 Jul 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

Now my question is, in this multi-file structure, will the feeds module parse this out-of-the-box, or will I need to get some other add on or create a custom parser??

What other solutions are out there for parsing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Feeds module can be setup to do this with XPath Parser and Feed Tamper. Give feeds tamper a try - https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper